# IE8 error while downloading a file

Tags: internet-explorer, download, http-headers

I am getting an error pop while downloading a file. Its only happening in IE8 on both windows XP and Windows 7. Once i click on download link this error is comming

"Unable to download 11820 from subdomain.domain.org" "Unable to open this internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later."

Here 11820 is the node id. I am using SSL certificate in my site though the url is https://subdomain.domain.org/

[image]

Comment: Can any one help. Is this related to SSL certification that we are using.

Comment: I am using drupal 7 with Apache 2 and oracle.

Comment: Can i try with function `custom_file_download_headers_alter(array &$headers, $file) { header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=15"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

`$headers = array(
       'Content-Type'              => 'force-download',
       'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename="' . $file->filename . '"',
       'Content-Length'            => $file->filesize,
       'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
       'Pragma'                    => 'private, no-cache',
       'Cache-Control'             => 'private, no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
       'Expires'                   => '0',
       'Accept-Ranges'             => 'bytes'
     );`